# Unable to copy file "C:\Data.dll" to "bin\Data.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Data.dll' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting below mention error in VS 2010. After getting this, Just restarting my machine and its working fine. But while hosting my application in windows server  2008 + IIS 7.0 its not working. Could you please suggest.

> Error 107 Unable to copy file "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\solution\Data.dll" to "bin\Debug\Data.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Data.dll' because it is being used by another process.Services
>
> Error 106 Unable to copy file "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\source\Business.dll" to "bin\Debug\Business.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Business.dll' because it is being used by another process.Services

Comment: You haven't said anything about what your application is trying to to, which makes it rather hard to help you. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: As a side note, Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) can tell you which process or processes have the file open.

Answer (score 3):

You are compiling the application while it is running and IIS is using the DLLs.

The result is that the compiled DLLs cannot be copied because IIS is using them.

Reset IIS (or at least recycle the relevant application pool) before compiling.

---

You may want to reconsider setting the IIS web application folder to the project output folder.

Comment: Hi I reseted the IIS and deleted all DLLs and recreated. there is no any errror but WCF method calling multiple times afteri got this error. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Build Configurations under (VS2010) `Build->Configuration Manager`.

All projects should be in Debug or Release mode, and also check that the project Build check box is checked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Command prompt

**copy source  destination** give full path of destination

copy C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\solution\Data.dll" "bin\Debug\Data.dll"

this is for copying file on the the same computer